# How to store console.log data to file?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have tree of objects:

```
let tree = {id: 1, children: [{id: 2, children: [{id: 3}]}]}
```

I want to store all `id` in this tree in file with tab for elements that have children:

```
1
  2
    3
```

I use this function to show elements of tree:

```
show(tag: XMLtag) {
    console.log(tag.show());

    if (tag.getChildren().length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    tag.getChildren().forEach((c) => {
        this.show(c);
    });
}
```

This function gives me:

```
1
2
3
```

Is it possible to write result to text file or display on the browser page with formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the inherent `console.log` function:

```js
var file = ''
console.log = (text) => {
    file += text + '\n';
}
// Call save() to save the file, you can do this onbeforeunload if you want or call it manually from console.

function save() {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = 'data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(file);
    link.innerHTML = 'download';
    link.download = 'Console_log.txt';     
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    link.remove();
}
```

Comment: Inside `save()`, what is `text`? And `document.body.appendChild(file)` appears to be adding a string to the body as if it were a child node, and that child node is never accessed. Why?

Comment: Whoops, thanks for reminding me of that @terrymorse

Comment: Glad to help. Also, I think you intended `document.body.appendChild(link)`, not '(file)'.

Answer (score 0):

```
const log = console.log
console.log = (logData) => {
   // append log to a file, something like this
   fs.appendFileSync('logs.txt', logData + '\n');
   // preserve original logging functionality
   log(logData)
}
```

This will work when only one argument is passed to console.log.

Comment: you need to specify front or backend in your question

Answer (score 0):

You can display formatted text on the page inside a `pre` element.

```js
const pre = document.querySelector('pre');

function addToDisplay(text) {
  pre.innerText += text + '\n';
}

addToDisplay('first line');
addToDisplay('    second line');
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Then add a line to the `show()` function:

```js
// add `indent` parameter to indent children
show(tag: XMLtag, indent = "") {
    console.log(tag.show());

 // add this to display indented items in browser:
    addToDisplay(indent + tag.show());

    if (tag.getChildren().length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    tag.getChildren().forEach((c) => {
        // indent children by an additional 2 spaces
        this.show(c, indent + "  ");
    });
}
```

Comment: How to add whitespace before all children?

Comment: @Aurica - see the changed `show()` function that indents each successive level by 2 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use node.js file system library. Checkout [fs.writeFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) or [fs.writeFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options)

```
const { writeFileSync } = require('fs')
writeFileSync('some-file.json', JSON.stringify({ id: 1, data: [{ id: 2 }, { id: 3 }] }, null, 2))
```

look for a `some-file.json` in the same directory